# Vue3 - How to work with cookies outside components?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, cookies

I need to use cookies to store the access token for the logged user in vue 3.
To do that, I'm using the 'vue-cookies' npm package.

It works flawlessly inside components - but I need to get the cookies outside components.

This is my main.ts in my vue 3 project:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies'
import router from './router'
import App from './App.vue'

import './assets/main.css'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)
app.use(VueCookies, { expires: '15m' })

app.mount('#app')
```

Inside "LoginItem.vue" component, I have the following piece of code with $cookies inside  tag:

```
// ...
    const $cookies = inject<VueCookies>('$cookies')
    const token = ref('')
// ...

    onMounted(() => {
      const accessToken = $cookies?.get('accessToken')
      if (accessToken) {
        token.value = accessToken
      }
    })
```

The above code works successfully. But I would like to create a global module/file/way to handle common operations with the access token.

So, I created the file "auth.ts" trying to use the same logic used for the component, but it didn't work unfortunately:

```
import { inject } from 'vue'
import type { VueCookies } from 'vue-cookies'

const $cookies = inject<VueCookies>('$cookies')

export const getToken = (): string => {
  return $cookies?.get('accessToken')
}
```

The `$cookie` is always undefined.

How can I fix that?

Also, in Vue 3 paradigm, is recommended to do this access token management in the way that I'm trying or should I seek for other approach?

Comment: It's a mistake to use `inject` anywhere but comp setup. There's no way how the framework could figure out what value to inject otherwise. What's the point of using it here? You can import it and use as is, provide/inject is needed for special cases with DI or circular deps

Comment: @EstusFlask sorry, I'm still learning vue3 and I still discovering how to get the things done. I just injected to see if would work

Comment: No problems, I posted an answer in case this helps

Answer (score 1):

It's a mistake to use `inject` anywhere but component setup and options API hooks that are executed at the same time (`created`, etc). `provide`/`inject` relies on component hierarchy, there's no way how the framework could figure out what value to inject otherwise.

A value can be imported directly and used instead, `provide`/`inject` is needed for a few special use cases, like dependency injection or avoiding circular dependencies.

It can be seen [here](https://github.com/cmp-cc/vue-cookies/blob/master/vue-cookies.js#L28) that plugin instance isn't exposed anywhere but application instance, so it will be available as `app.$cookies`, it can be used in non-component modules but may result in circular dependencies. Not resolving CD efficiently will result in an application that can't be bundled in some environments. CD restrictions can be relaxed in this case by extracting application instance to separate module and not referring root component instantly on import, e.g. app.js:

```
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
export const app = createApp({ render: () => h(App) })
```

Then `app` is imported in main.js and other modules that need to access `app.$cookies`.

It's useful to use reactive global store and not cookies as a single source of truth, a store can be synchronized to cookies or local storage. This can be easily achieved with Pinia store and persistence plugin. Since Pinia is already used here, this is the preferable way. The stores can be imported directly anywhere and avoid related problems with CD mentioned above.